# Converting a weekly forecast (Pandas df) into monthly format

Tags: python, pandas, forecasting

I have a process which produces a dataframe containing a forecasting for products (and versions) in a weekly format (wc/ Monday dates - column names as strings). Example:

```
product     version     2021-06-07     2021-06-14     2021-06-21     2021-06-28

   a           1           500            400            300            200

   a           2           750            600            450            200

   b           1           200            150            100            100

   b           2           500            400            300            200
```

I've been asked to change the forecast into a monthly forecast instead of a weekly one. Example:

```
product     version       Jun-21         Jul-21         Aug-21         Sep-21

   a           1           350             x              x              x

   a           2           500             x              x              x
 
   b           1           100             x              x              x

   b           2           350             x              x              x
```

Numbers are for show - what I'm trying to do is average the weekly columns (for each row) to create monthly outputs but in an accurate fashion, i.e. if  a weekly column was wc/ 26th Feb, then only 3 days worth will be included in the average for February and only 4 days for March.

I know that this is only a question of formatting / bucketing but I am struggling to come up with a solution as I've never had to do something like this before.

Not expecting a full solution but a point in the right direction for how I should approach the task would be much appreciated.

Comment: For your last week of the month (2021-06-28), 200 is divided into 2 parts: 200*3/7 for june and 200*4/7 for july? How to deal with 2021-05-31?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a process, since you need to calculate days in the month, identify which ones flow into the next month, do the math and shift them forward.  This should do the trick.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'product': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
 'version': [1, 2, 1, 2],
 '6/7/2021': [500, 750, 200, 500],
 '6/14/2021': [400, 600, 150, 400],
 '6/21/2021': [300, 450, 100, 300],
 '6/28/2021': [200, 200, 100, 200],
 })

# Convert data to long format
df = df.melt(id_vars=['product','version'], var_name='date')
# Convert date to datetime object
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# Add 7 days to the day of the month to compare to the number of days in a month
df['month_day'] = df['date'].dt.day + 7

# Get the number of days in the month
df['days_in_month'] = df['date'].dt.daysinmonth

# Subtract to see how many days the current date would extend into the next month
df['overrun'] = df['month_day']-df['days_in_month']

# Calculate the percentage of the values to push forward into the next month
df['push_forward'] = np.where(df['overrun']>0, df['value']/df['days_in_month']*df['overrun'], 0)

# Reduce the current values by the amount to be pushed forward
df['value'] = df['value'] - df['push_forward']

# Copy the records with a push_forward value to a new dataframe
df2 = df.loc[df['push_forward']>0].copy()

# Drop push_foward column
df.drop(columns='push_forward', inplace=True)

# Add a week to the date values of records with a push_foward value
df2['date'] = df2['date']+pd.DateOffset(weeks=1)

# Merge the pushed data back to the original dataframe
df = df.merge(df2[['product','version','date','push_forward']], on=['product','version','date'], how='outer')

# Fill null values
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

# Add the push forward values to their respective weekly values
df['value'] = df['value'] + df['push_forward']

# Convert date to just the month
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

# Group and take the average
df = df.groupby(['product','version','date'])['value'].mean().reset_index()


# # Create final pivot table
df.pivot_table(index=['product','version'], columns='date', values='value')
```

Output

```
            date       2021-06    2021-07
product version     
      a        1    341.666667  33.333333
               2    491.666667  33.333333
      b        1    133.333333  16.666667
               2    341.666667  33.333333
```

Comment: The only thing I have amended is changing the "add 7 days" to "add 6 days" so that, for example, a weekly date of '2018-12-31' will still have 1 day which falls into the 2018-12 bucket (as the forecast is inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by [melting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the Dataframe into long-form (instead of wide-form). In the example below, we translate into long-form, group by the year-month pairs, take the mean, then translate back to wide-form. During the `melt` and `pivot` operations, some multi-indexes are created, so we have to handle that as well (last line of code).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "product": ["a", "a", "b", 'b'],
    "version": ["1", "2", "1", '2'],
    "2021-06-07": [500, 750, 200, 500],
    "2021-06-14": [400, 600, 150, 400],
    "2021-06-21": [300, 450, 100, 300],
    "2021-06-28": [200, 200, 100, 200],
    "2021-07-07": [500, 750, 200, 500],
    "2021-07-14": [400, 600, 150, 400],
    "2021-07-21": [300, 450, 100, 300],
    "2021-07-28": [200, 200, 100, 200],
})

# First, we melt into long-form data
df = df.melt(id_vars=['product', 'version'], var_name='date')

# Truncate the string to only use year-month format
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x[:7])

# Group by product/version/date, then take the mean
df = df.groupby(['product', 'version', 'date']).mean()

# Pivot back to wide-form table
df = df.pivot_table(index=['product', 'version'], columns='date').reset_index()

# Reset column index from multi-index to single string
df.columns = [x[0] if not x[1] else x[1] for x in df.columns]
```